# Sysprep and unattend.xml: remove local user account on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, deployment, sysprep, unattended

We are deploying Windows 7 using WDS. We want to remove the local user account which was created during setup. We don't need this account since the machines join a domain and a domain user account is created during OOBE phase.

Documentation of `Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup | UserAccounts | LocalAccounts` states that this option can **create** local accounts.

Is there a way to specify accounts to be deleted in a `unattend.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use Audit Mode when creating your Sysprep image. Audit Mode enables you to customize a Windows installation without prompting to create user accounts and configure your location and time zone.

Reference:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722413(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722413%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use a cmd file with `net user  "user name" /delete`

part of `Unattend.xml`:

```
        <FirstLogonCommands>
            <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                <Description>Executing lastboot script</Description>
                <Order>1</Order>
                <CommandLine>c:\temp\lastboot.cmd</CommandLine>
            </SynchronousCommand>
            <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                <Description>logoff corrent user</Description>
                <Order>2</Order>
                <CommandLine>shutdown /l /f</CommandLine>
            </SynchronousCommand>
        </FirstLogonCommands>
```